# Scan over array of images

Tags: image-processing

I would like to take in an array of images as input, and then call the ColorSeparate function on each of them, and retrieve this as output.

So far I have the following :

```
test1 = Import[
  "C:\\filelocation\\*.jpg"]
Scan[ColorSeparate, test1]
```

This correctly obtains the array of images, however the Scan does not appear to produce an output. Have I approached this in the wrong way, and how might I be able to get output from this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation of `Scan`:

> Scan[f,expr] discards the results of applying f to the subexpressions
>   in expr. Unlike Map, Scan does not build up a new expression to
>   return.

So what you actually want is

```
Map[ColorSeparate,test1]
```

or

```
ColorSeparate/@test1
```

Answer (score 2):

Like Graumagier has said, the function `Scan` does not return.

So if you want to see the "Scan", you must print it out since there is no return:

```
Scan[Print[ColorSeparate[#]] &, test1]
```

Or otherwise, you want to get a returned value, then use `Map`.

```
Map[ColorSeparate, test1]
```